# Concatenate data from two columns of a CSV file using Ant

Tags: csv, ant

Is there a way to create a new column in a csv file which includes the concatenation of two other columns joined with a `"-"` - Using Ant?

**example:**

```
customer,deal,NEWFIELD
200000042,23,200000042-23
200000042,34,200000042-34
200000042,35,200000042-35    
200000042,65,200000042-65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be simpler to embedd a scripting language like Groovy?

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── file1.csv
└── target
    └── file1.csv
```

### src/file1.csv

```
customer,deal
200000042,23
200000042,34
200000042,35
200000042,65
```

### target/file1.csv

```
customer,deal,customer-deal
200000042,23,200000042-23
200000042,34,200000042-34
200000042,35,200000042-35
200000042,65,200000042-65
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <available classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" property="groovy.installed"/>

  <target name="build" depends="install-groovy">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

    <groovy>
      ant.mkdir(dir:"target")

      new File("target/file1.csv").withWriter {
        new File("src/file1.csv").splitEachLine(",") { customer, deal ->
           it.println "${customer},${deal},${customer}-${deal}"
        }
      }
    </groovy>
  </target>

  <target name="install-groovy" description="Install groovy" unless="groovy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.7/groovy-all-2.4.7.jar"/>
    <fail message="Groovy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it is work perfectly  just few question if I may: My columns are in hebrew, any way to deal with it? and does Groovy can be installed on windows server 2008? Thanks again!

Comment: Another issue, when the script ran into empty cell it throw exception.. =\

Comment: @AlonSegal Example updated in other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407444/quotes-appearing-on-csv-after-concatnate-fields-using-groovy/41417408#41417408

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Ant [filterchains](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html), something like this basic example:

```
<property name="in.file" value="input.txt" />
<property name="out.file" value="output.txt" />
<property name="new.field" value="NEWFIELD" />
<property name="sep.char" value="," />

<loadfile srcfile="${in.file}" property="file.head">
  <filterchain>
    <headfilter lines="1" />
    <striplinebreaks />
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<loadfile srcfile="${in.file}" property="file.body">
  <filterchain>
    <headfilter skip="1" />
    <tokenfilter>
        <replaceregex pattern="^([^${sep.char}]*)${sep.char}([^${sep.char}]*)$"
                      replace="\1${sep.char}\2${sep.char}\1-\2" />
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>

<echo file="${out.file}">${file.head}${sep.char}${new.field}
${file.body}</echo>
```

Two [`<loadfile>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) tasks are used to process the header and body of the file, then a simple `<echo>` task to write the output.  A simplistic regular expression works here as the number of fields in the CSV file is small.  The `replaceregex` uses capturing groups to get the first two fields on the line, then in the `replace` string assembles the required output.

If there are several fields, then perhaps a [`scriptfilter`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#scriptfilter) in the second `loadfile` would be simper to work with:

```
<loadfile srcfile="${in.file}" property="file.body">
  <filterchain>
    <headfilter skip="1" />
    <scriptfilter language="javascript"><![CDATA[
      var line = self.getToken( );
      var fields = line.split( "," );
      self.setToken( line + "," + fields[0] + "-" + fields[1] );
    ]]></scriptfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

This one takes the line, splits it and then appends the required fields.

*Neither example here would work if your data contains embedded commas.*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback but i'm a bit newbie on ant. I didnt understand how to concatenation happened

Comment: The concat in the first example was done using a regular expression and substitution.