# Quotes appearing on CSV after concatnate fields using Groovy

Tags: csv, groovy, ant

I'm using groovy to concatenate two fields in CSV
It's working ok except that the concatenated field is appearing with quotes.

Is there any way to resolve this?

[image]

```
      ant.mkdir(dir:"target")

  new File("target/UpsertCheckDeals.csv").withWriter {
    new File("C:/Users/alon/Documents/CheckDealReadyForConcat.csv").splitEachLine(",") {Customer__c,Name__c,Deal__c,Check_Count__c ->
    it.println "${Customer__c},${Deal__c},${Deal_Source__c},${Salesperson_Name__c},${Customer__c}-${Deal__c}"
```

Comment: Because there are quotes in the original file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 0 to empty csv cells using Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396432/add-0-to-empty-csv-cells-using-groovy)

Comment: How does it a duplicate? I asked on the other question how to put o on empty cells and here I asked about quotation remove - Tim, There arnt any quotes in the original file

Comment: What do the two files look like in a text editor? Don't load them into excel by double clicking them, excel is awful

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a more complicated file format than it would [first appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971542/field-size-limitation-of-csv-file/9972468#9972468). Fields can be optionally quoted which is what appears to be your problem.

Most programming languages have a library that will parse CSV. In the case of groovy I'd recommend opencsv

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

The following example extends the example I created for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311501/concatenate-data-from-two-columns-of-a-csv-file-using-ant/41365039#41365039).

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── file1.csv
└── target
    └── file1.csv
```

### src/file1.csv

```
"customer",deal
"200000042",23
"200000042",34
"200000042",35
"200000042",65
```

### target/file1.csv

```
customer,deal,customer-deal
200000042,23,200000042-23
200000042,34,200000042-34
200000042,35,200000042-35
200000042,65,200000042-65
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/>

  <target name="build" depends="resolve">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <groovy>
      import com.opencsv.CSVReader

      ant.mkdir(dir:"target")

      new File("target/file1.csv").withWriter { writer ->
        new File("src/file1.csv").withReader { reader ->
          CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(reader);

          csv.iterator().each { row ->
            if (row.size() == 2) {
              writer.println "${row[0]},${row[1]},${row[0]}-${row[1]}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </groovy>
  </target>

  <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy"> 
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
      <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="2.4.7" conf="default"/>
      <dependency org="com.opencsv" name="opencsv" rev="3.8" conf="default"/>
    </ivy:cachepath>
  </target>

  <target name="install-ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>
    <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- Uses [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to managed dependencies like groovy and opencsv
- I included a test "row.size() == 2" to prevent empty rows throwing errors